# коррелированный запрос

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

У меня есть БД oracle 10 xe и sqldeveloper. Как на нем можно посмотреть как выполняется запрос? Ну как, например, в какой-нибудь ide, когда ставишь точки останова и смотришь что делает каждая операция. Хочу посмотреть как выполняется коррелированный вложенный запрос. Не пойму как выполняется. Или объясните как он раьотает. Вот скрин таблицы и запрос:[image: таблица]

```
select distinct А.код_продукта 
from поставки А 
where А.код_продукта not in (select Б.код_продукта 
                             from поставки Б 
                             where Б.код_поставщика <> А.код_поставщика) 
order by код_продукта
;
```

Comment: Поищите в меню что нибудь про explain или plan, он покажет то что обычно получают с помощью команды `explain plan запрос`, т.е. план выполнения запроса, в котором показано в каком порядке он обращатся к таблицам, какие при этом использует индексы и методы объединения результатов. В зависимости от множества факторов, таких как: наличие подходящих индексов, их селективность, кол-во записей и т.п. оптимизатор может выполнять одинаковые с виду запросы совершенно по разному

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070910/how-do-i-view-the-explain-plan-in-oracle-sql-developer